# I need someone to explain extracting these string from a inputbox

Tags: arrays, string, delphi

delphi 2010

I have a procedure in which the user enters in their name and surname and then i extract the surname and name into two different strings. Can someone please explain the significance of the +1,3 and pos' ' in the code, and when would those values need to be changed?(e.g why is it +1 and not +2) thank you

```
procedure TForm1.GenerateOnceoffPassword1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
suser, ssurname, sname, spassword : string; 
arrpassword : array[1..150] of string;  
begin
inc(icounter); 
suser := inputbox('Enter name and surname','lower case ONLY','');
ssurname := copy(suser,pos(' ',suser)+1, 3); 
sname := copy(suser, 1, pos(' ',suser)-1);
```

Comment: So you'll be asking for every single `Pos` and `Copy` usecase ? Isn't that wasting of time ? Wouldn't be better for you to understand how these functions work ?

Comment: What i dont understand is why do we need to use the +1,3 and the 1,=1. from my understanding it means starting from the first char up until the end of the next. (E.g: copy(arrsurname[k],1,3) from the first letter of arrsurname to the third) is this correct?

Comment: If you don't understand why they're ther, **take them off** and compare the differences. It shouldn't be necessary to have your hand held to answer simple questions like this - do some experimentation to try and figure things out yourself. You were given the information in your last question, but seem to be making no effort to actually **learn** from the answers.

Comment: try googling `Delphi Pos() string` and `Delphi Copy() string`. You're outrageously lazy.

Comment: Do you know how the debugger works?

Comment: What if either name has a space in it?

Comment: In Delphi XE2, [`InputQuery()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) was updated to support multiple inputs at a time. So the user can type their name in one field and their surname in another field within the same dialog, and they will be returned as separate strings, no need to separate them manually.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've looked up the Copy and Pos functions in the OLH or elsewhere.  So, dealing with your points in your q and comment:

a. The "+1" in "copy(suser,pos(' ',suser)+1, 3)" means that the call to Copy should start at the first character after the first occurrence of a space character in suser returned by the call to Pos().  If Pos() finds no space in suser, it will return 0, so copying would then start at the first character of suser.  See also point 2 below.

b.  The "3" means that Copy should copy (at most) 3 characters from where it has been told to start copying by "pos() + 1".  I say "at most" because that's how Copy() works and nothing in your code compels the user to enter a string having 3 or more characters after the first space.  Seems a bit odd that a surname should be restricted to a maximum of 3 characters, btw.

c.  Presumably referring to "1,=1" in your comment, you actually meant "1,=-1" Anyway, The "1" in the second call to Copy() means "start copying from the first character of suser", and the "pos() - 1" means copy at most X characters where X is one less than the value returned by the call to pos(), in other words copy the characters from suser up to one before the first occurrence of a space.  If there is no space in suser, this will result in sname being empty.

Be aware that:

1. When using functions like Pos() and Copy() to split strings up, it's a good idea to get into the habit of using the Trim() function to remove any leading or trailing spaces from the substring(s).  In point a. above, your code as written overlooks the possibility that the user might type two (or more) consecutive spaces.
2. Rather than prompt the user to use lower-case only, it would be better to get into the habit of writing code which works regardless of case.  Obviously this isn't an issue with the specific code in your q, but anyway.
3. Traditionally, strings in Delphi have been 1-based, meaning that, if non-blank, inter alia the string can be accessed as if it were an array with a starting index of 1.  Newer versions of the compiler (newer than D2010, that is) for mobile platforms like Android use 0-based strings, which cause the arithmetic of code like yours to be problematic if used unmodified.